# WordPress: show archive even though there are no posts

Tags: php, wordpress

On my WordPress website, I have an archive page e.g.: `http://www.example.com/2017`. My archive.php file has a query to show **posts** as well as two custom post types: **case-studies** and **media**:

```
global $wp_query;
        $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => array('post','case-studies','media'), 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
        query_posts( $args );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

The archive page will only show provided there are posts under **post** (the standard post type that is included within WordPress) otherwise it will 404, even though there are posts under **case-studies** and **media**.

Is there a workaround this?

Here is a link to my archive.php for those who are interested: [archive.php](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=01176873805470321208&t=0117687380547032120854071)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before. You can include a function in your `functions.php` file which can redirect the page to `archive.php` instead of the usual 404. See if this works:

```
function wpd_date_404_template( $template = '' ){
   global $wp_query;
      if( isset($wp_query->query['year'])
          || isset($wp_query->query['monthnum'])
          || isset($wp_query->query['day']) ){
          $template = locate_template( 'archive.php', false );
      }
   return $template;
}
add_filter( '404_template', 'wpd_date_404_template' );
```

Credit to [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo) at the WordPress StackExchange. See his answer here: [Preventing 404 error on empty date archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142142)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this now.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpd_date_404_template( $template = '' ){
    global $wp_query;
    if(
        isset($wp_query->query['year']) ||
        isset($wp_query->query['monthnum']) ||
        isset($wp_query->query['day'])
    ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'archive.php', false );

        if ( isset( $wp_query->query['post_type'] ) ) {
            $located = locate_template( 'archive-' . $wp_query->query['post_type'] . '.php', false );
            $template = $located !== '' ? $located : locate_template( 'archive.php', false );
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( '404_template', 'wpd_date_404_template' );
```

Just used @Dev1997 his answer to solve the issue. With a small improvement to use the specific template for the current (custom) post_type. Maybe it will help someone who is using custom post types.